# Загрузка файлов для карточки Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, файлы, storage

Есть код который должен загружать файл для карточки дома. Но файл не загружается, сам дом создается но поле passport не заполняется, а так же не создаётся папка на сервере.

**Controller@store**

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'passport' => 'required'
]);

$homes = Houses::query()->create([
  'passport' => $request->get('passport')
]);

$request->validate([
  'file' => 'required|mimes:docs,txt,doc,xls,pdf,docx, docm,rtf,xps,xml|max:4098'
]);

$fileModel = new File;

if ($request->has('file')) {
   $file = $request->file;

   $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $filename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        

   $fileName = time() . '_' . $filename.'.'.$ext;
   $filePath = $file->storeAs('passport_house', $fileName, 'public');

   $fileModel->name = $fileName;
   $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
   $fileModel->save();
}

return redirect()->route('homes.index');
}
```

Где моя ошибка, покажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Если файл не передается вовсе, то возможно не проставлена enctype= multipart/form-data на форме

```
<form enctype= multipart/form-data ...></form>
```

Для загрузки файлов рекомендую Laravel Media Library. Удобная вещь.